# Artifacts from fileTree

Tags: java, gradle, jar

my gradle project contains compiles of MavenCentral and compiles of a local fileTree. I try to iterate all dependecies and print the artifact information. The output only contains those  deps of maven and not from the local dir. The question is how can I print the dependencies from the fileTree?

```
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:+'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile fileTree(dir: '..\\mylibs', include: '*.jar')
}

task showConf << {
    configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        println(artifact.moduleVersion.id.group + " " + artifact.moduleVersion.id.name + " " + artifact.moduleVersion.id.version)
    }
}
```

Output:

> org.slf4j slf4j-api 1.7.12,
>   joda-time joda-time 2.9,
>   log4j log4j 1.2.17

Comment: And what is your question?